# Align to largest element in a RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I'm designing a simple layout using a RelativeLayout, i would like to avoid nested LinearLayouts or other nested viewgroups.
There are 9 views, it all shows like this:

[image]

I don't know how to correctly align seekbars to avoid text overlapping or wrapping lines.
Aligning from right: rgb images width is fixed, seekbars width (all the same) depends on the labels width, i want it to depend on the largest one.
How to know what label to refer to with `android:layout_toRightOf` or what?

The above image also shows two behaviours i'd like to avoid:
--aligning refers to first label (@id/text1)--
2nd row: `android:layout_alignRight` missing make a longer text overlap.
3rd row: `android:layout_alignRight` is present but longer text wraps.

Here's what i would like:

[image]

Should i measure the TextViews width to find the largest one (programmatically, of course...)?

Any idea for an XML solution?

Here's the code:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/addon"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="@color/semi_transparent_background_controls"
    android:visibility="visible" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/seek1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Normal text"/>

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seek1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/img1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/text1"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@id/img1"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:src="@drawable/img1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/seek2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/img1"
        android:text="Longer text overlaps"/>

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seek2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/seek1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/img2"
        android:layout_below="@id/seek1"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/img2"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@id/img2"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:src="@drawable/img2"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/img1"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/seek3"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_below="@id/img2"
        android:text="or wraps to a new line"/>

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seek3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/seek1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/img3"
        android:layout_below="@id/seek2"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/img3"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@id/img3"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:src="@drawable/img3"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/img2"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Not 100% sure, but what if you align_right all of the text views, then layout_toRightOf the seekbars?

Comment: @GabeSechan do you mean gravity="right" for all textviews?

Comment: Try to fix SeekBar width.

Comment: @Haresh of course that's the point! But how wide? It all depends on labels, in different languages textviews width can be very different, i don't want an empty space nor an overlapping...